# What is the the difference in Chrome DevTools between checked and crossed out CSS styling?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

I want to center a div in the middle of the screen. That's why I am overriding some CSS rules. I wrote the rules again and set !important. (Please see the printscreen. The discussed rules are marked in red.)

[image]

As you can see the old rules are crossed out now but it still doesn't work. It only works when I manually uncheck the rules. (Yellow Checkbox on the left)

I checked it out in Firefox and the overridden rules are not crossed. This means the issue is probably related to the override.

[image]

What is the difference and how can I fix that?

Comment: I'd hazard your media query should be max not min.

Comment: It is mobile first. That fix is just for desktops.

Comment: Have you checked your page width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything that's checked is active; all things are checked by default when you open the inspector and you can uncheck individual property-value pairs to temporarily disable them, either until you refresh or check the box again.

Everything that's crossed out is something that's currently being overwritten by another property-value pair somewhere else, either in the same selector or in another selector somewhere. It is being overwritten because a value is either the same but written second (like a shorthand property used after a specific one), or it could be overwritten because there is a more specific selector somewhere with the exact same property somewhere.